# Oracle Stored Procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, oracle11g

My question is pretty basic but I am complete newbie to stored procedure and need to get around quickly. Any help will be appreciated,

Below is the current stored procedure we have,

```
PROCEDURE get_something(
type  IN VARCHAR2,
value IN VARCHAR2,
i_type OUT VARCHAR2,
i_id OUT VARCHAR2)
AS
TYPE t_array
IS
   TABLE OF VARCHAR2(320);
   identifers t_array;
   column_name VARCHAR2(32);
   info_qry    VARCHAR2(500);
   top_row_qry    VARCHAR2(500);
BEGIN
identifers  := t_array('ABC');
column_name   := get_column_name(type);

info_qry := 'select INS.i_id,  INS.model from table1 INS where  INS.'||column_name||'='''||value||''' order by INS.version desc';


top_row_qry := 'select * from ('||info_qry||') where rownum<=1';

EXECUTE immediate top_row_qry INTO i_id, i_type;

EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
i_id   := NULL;
i_type := NULL;
END get_something;
```

Now when I execute this procedure, it gives me one record due to the rownum condition.

My requirement is to remove the rownum from the top_row_qry, so result would be multiple rows.

I want to store each field into some variable out of which I will use one of the variable for some comparison in the procedure itself.

So basically i want to store the results which I can later loop over and compare with a list of values.

Also, I need to define the list of values in this procedure itself.

Something like below:

```
   list_of_vals:= t_array('ABC','XYZ');
```

Can anyone help me on this.

Comment: https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/loops/cursor_for.php

Comment: Yes as mentioned by OldProgrammer - the solution is to use cursors when more than one rows are to be manipulated in pl/sql

Comment: Use `bulk collect` into a collection

Comment: Yes,i used bulk collect into for my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to use cursor as OUT parameter for your procedure and later use it for your requirement.

Also for "*I need to define the list of values in this procedure itself.*"
you can use a collection the way I have used in the procedure code (v_array).
You can then use a loop to traverse through multiple values for the v_array.

```
CREATE ORE REPLACE PROCEDURE get_something(type  IN VARCHAR2,
                                           value IN VARCHAR2,
                                           out_param OUT sys_refcursor)
AS
  TYPE t_array IS  TABLE OF VARCHAR2(320);
  v_array t_array:=t_array();
  -- identifers t_array;
  column_name VARCHAR2(32);
  info_qry    VARCHAR2(500);
  top_row_qry    VARCHAR2(500);
BEGIN
--To define multiple values for a collection e.g. ABC, XYZ
  v_array.EXTEND(2) ;
  v_array(1):='ABC' ;
  v_array(2):='XYZ' ;
  --identifers  := t_array('ABC') ;
  column_name   := get_column_name(TYPE) ;

  info_qry := 'select INS.i_id,  INS.model from table1 INS where  INS.'||column_name||'='''||VALUE||''' order by INS.version desc';

  top_row_qry := 'select * from ('||info_qry||')' ;

  OPEN out_param FOR top_row_qry ;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    OPEN out_param FOR 'select null, null from dual' ;
END get_something ;
/

--To execute the procedure
DECLARE
  lv_type VARCHAR2(200);
  lv_id NUMBER;
  lv_cur SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
  get_something('param1','param2',lv_cur);
  LOOP
    FETCH lv_cur INTO lv_id,lv_type;
    EXIT WHEN lv_cur%NOTFOUND;
      --Do something.....
  END LOOP;
END;
```